# Grid Layout and Button inside input box in next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a UI similar to that of chatpgt where the past conversations are previewed on the left, whereas the current conversation is shown on the right. I've set it up to be in grid format with 7 columns, the previous chats taking up 1, and the current taking up 7. Is there a better way of doing this? Also not sure on how to get a button inside of an input box and make it so that it will stay in the middle of the input box vertically as the user types in a longer message and the input box grows. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SendChatButton from '@/components/buttons/SendChatButton';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faPenToSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


export default function Home() {
  
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const clearInput = () => setInputValue('');
  
  return (
    <div className='m-0 w-full h-screen grid grid-cols-7' style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 60px)' }}>
      <div className='bg-gray-200 col-span-1 left-0 p-1'>
      <button className='w-full rounded-lg p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 flex justify-between items-center'>
        <span>New Chat</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} />
      </button>
      </div>
      <div className='col-span-6 flex flex-col'>
        <div className='grow'>
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center p-4 outline-none w-full mx-auto sticky bottom-0">
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            className="w-2/4 p-4 border rounded-xl outline-none"
            placeholder="Message FashionFinder..."
          />
          <SendChatButton inputValue={inputValue} clearInput={clearInput} className="w=full"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `grid-cols-7` to `grid-cols-8` or `grid-cols-5`, depending on how much space you want for each part. If using `grid-cols-8`, you could have `col-span-2` for previous chats and `col-span-6` for the current chat. If using `grid-cols-5`, `col-span-1` for previous chats and `col-span-4` for the current chat might be more suitable.

To get a button inside an input box and ensure it stays in the middle vertically, you can use a wrapper `div` around the input and button, set the `div` to be a flex container, and then align items in the center. This approach is more about CSS than React itself.

Look at following code

```
export default function Home() {
  
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const clearInput = () => setInputValue('');
  
  return (
    <div className='m-0 w-full h-screen grid grid-cols-8' style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 60px)' }}> {/* Adjusted to grid-cols-8 */}
      <div className='bg-gray-200 col-span-2 left-0 p-1'> {/* Adjusted to col-span-2 */}
        <button className='w-full rounded-lg p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 flex justify-between items-center'>
          <span>New Chat</span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className='col-span-6 flex flex-col'>
        <div className='grow'>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center p-4 w-full mx-auto sticky bottom-0">
          <div className="flex w-3/4 border rounded-xl items-center"> {/* Adjusted wrapper class */}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={inputValue}
              onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
              className="flex-grow p-4 rounded-l-xl outline-none" /* Adjusted input class */
              placeholder="Message FashionFinder..."
            />
            <SendChatButton inputValue={inputValue} clearInput={clearInput} className="w-auto"/> {/* Adjusted button class */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```